# Creating a modified primary in MySQL

Tags: mysql, primary-key

Suppose I've a table inside my database.
Table name : employees

I've a primary key, which is employee_id. I want this primary key to have a form of EMP-001.
Auto increment will take place on that 001 portion only, how can I do that? 
Is there any process to do that inside MySQL, or shall I create a different db_method inside project like Generate_ID and use that to generate that kind of employee id?

Comment: Store it as int and cast it later if the format is universal.  Why would you want your DB comparing strings over int for lookup

Comment: I am asked to establish a logic so that the primary key that we'll be using will have a form of EMP-00X where X will start from 1 and will get incremented by 1 every time an employee is being registered.

Comment: Is it the intention that prefixes other than emp will be used?

Comment: If there's no process available inside MySQL for this, then I think it would be better to create a java class and then get the employee_id from there and storing it inside database afterwards.

Comment: They want to use "EMP-" as prefix here.

Comment: If the prefix is only ever going to be emp then there's no point to doing this and if you are only planning on 3 digits then you will have to manage  recycling of emp number. What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: I'm on mysql-installer-community-5.7.21.0